# Unable to install Network Deployment Enrollment Services (NDES)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, security, windows-server-2008-r2, certificate

I'm trying to install NDES on a Win2k8 R2 server, but I can't see the option.

[image]

I've already added a user to IIS_IUSRS, and that user as sufficient priveleges since it is a part of the Administrator (BuiltIn) user group as well.

Please tell me as to what am I missing here.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point here... 
What is NDES, and what is the actual error message?

Comment: NDES- Network Deployment Enrollment Services. I want to install the server role. According to guides on the internet, this is where the option is supposed to show up. It isn't.

Comment: Got it. Have you rebooted the computer? It needs a reboot after installing & configuring the CA

Comment: There are actually conflicting information. There is also this: 7.   On the Select Role Services screen, clear Certification Authority and select Network Device Enrollment Service. `As I mentioned previously, NDES can’t be installed on the same machine as a CA.`

Comment: Restarting isn't helping. Apparently, it can be on the same as CA, here's a pic of how's it supposed to: http://i58.tinypic.com/qn7h35.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't show up unless you're running Enterprise/Datacenter editions of Windows Server 2008 R2. This however does not matter in 2012 R2.

[From the ADCS: NDES Wiki article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9063.network-device-enrollment-service-ndes-in-active-directory-certificate-services-ad-cs.aspx):

> One major difference between Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2012 is that starting with Windows Server 2012, the NDES role service is available in all Windows Server 2012 versions. See the AD CS Overview article for the table that shows the AD CS roles that are not available in some Windows Server 2008 R2 versions. The important point for this article is that **Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, Web Server, and Foundation editions do not support the NDES role service.** Further, installations of Windows Server 2008 R2 using Server Core do not support NDES. Since Small Business Server (SBS) 2011 is based on Windows Server 2008 R2 standard, the NDES role service is not available on that platform either.